# Convert json to Query

Tags: python, logic, nested-loops

I am trying to build a query builder to be processed by Pandas query. So below is the structure.

```
{ ["AND", ["OR", ["AND", {
            "Property": "ColumnA",
            "Operand": ">",
            "Value": "56"
        }, {
            "Property": "ColumnA",
            "Operand": "<",
            "Value": "78"
        }],
        ["AND", {
            "Property": "ColumnA",
            "Operand": "==",
            "Value": "99"
        }]
    ], {
        "Property": "ColumnB",
        "Operand": "==",
        "Value": "true"
    }]
}
```

So result should be like this, we ignore the condition if associated with single object else concatenate with other result

`((ColumnA > 56 and ColumnA < 78) or ColumnA == 99) and ColumnB == true)`

so below is some things I am trying

Below function get the type

```
def represents_number(s):
    try:
        number = float(s) if float(s) else int(s)
        return number
    except ValueError:
        return False


def represents_boolean(s):
    if s.lower() in ("false", "true"):
        if s.lower() == "true":
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return 'error'


def check_type(value):
    boolean_type = represents_boolean(value)
    if boolean_type != 'error':
        return boolean_type
    else:
        num = represents_number(value)
        if type(num) is float:
            return num
        else:
            return f'{value}'
```

this function creates condition string

```
def get_query_string(query: dict):
    if query['Value'] == 'null':
        new_condition = f" {query['Property']}.isnull()"
        return new_condition
    value = check_type(query['Value'])
    if isinstance(value, str):
        new_condition = f" {query['Property']} {query['Operand']} '{value}' "
    else:
        new_condition = f" {query['Property']} {query['Operand']} {value} "
    return new_condition
```

This function builds condition if there is list of objects

```
def build_condition(lst, join_condition):
    query_string = ''
    condition = []
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            condition.append(get_query_string(item))
    query_string = join_condition.join(condition)
    query_string = '({})'.format(query_string)
    return query_string
```

and finally this function I am trying to create to build final query

```
join_conditions = []
def Process(lst, query):
    global join_conditions
    
    for idx, x in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(x, list):
            if len(x) > 2 and isinstance(x[1], dict) and isinstance(x[2], dict):
                join_condition = join_conditions[idx]
                condition = build_condition(x, x[0])
                query = f"{query} {join_condition} {condition}"
            else:
                Process(x, query)
        elif isinstance(x, dict) and query == '' and len(lst) == 2:
            condition = get_query_string(x)
            query = condition
        elif isinstance(x, dict):
            #code here
        else: 
            join_conditions.append(x)
            
                
    return query
```

What I am struggling is associate conditions to join 2 leaf node. Need some directions here
Thank you

Comment: What is the issue that you ae having with when associate conditions to join 2 leaf node?

Comment: So I am missing the mapping, which condition is for which mapping. If I can associate condition between 2 leaf. I will be able to create the query.

Comment: A problem that you have currently is that `Process(x, query)` needs to be updated to `query = Process(x, query)` as the values are not being updated when you call that function and ultimately returning the values. Your major problem is that instead of going deeper down the tree and building it deepest in towards the broadest based on the list structure you have, you are using `enumerate(lst)` which only cycles through some of the input and only partially creates the string that you want. would recommend looking at recursion for this problem

Answer (score 0):

As per @Andrew's suggestion, created a dictionary using a while loop rather than recusing which helped me with the position of joins.